# Why Client method called for 4 times in siganlR?

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I am beignner in signalR core and i am trying to learn it . i follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SgW0mn8MkE) step by step and every thing working fine except **Client method called for 4 times in siganlR ?**

**result :**

[image: photo]

**Hub :**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace signalR
{
    public class Chat:Hub
    {
        public async  Task SendMessage(string user,string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ForwardToClients", user,message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chat").configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information).build();
connection.on("ForwardToClients", (user, message) => {
    const encoding = user + "Says:" + message;
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encoding;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().catch(er => console.log(er.toString()));
document.getElementById("sendMessage").addEventListener("click", event => {
    const user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    const message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(er => console.log(er.toString()));    
});
```

please can anyone help me ? !

Comment: How many tabs are open in your browser? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587888/different-connection-in-browser-multiple-tabs

Comment: @rad two tabs and i tried open two windows of Google Chrome but still get the same action